# Specify properties for objects inside an array of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have an interface that looks like this:

```
    export interface Stats {

    lastFiveResults: Object[];

}
```

The array of objects looks this this:

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {idresults: 500, gold: 567740, mana: 305370, xp: 1800}
1: {idresults: 501, gold: 492381, mana: 602707, xp: 1450}
2: {idresults: 502, gold: 241012, mana: 303954, xp: 810}
3: {idresults: 503, gold: 415778, mana: 261254, xp: 810}
4: {idresults: 504, gold: 327266, mana: 427803, xp: 0}
```

And when I try and access it like this

```
data.lastFiveMatches[0].gold
```

I get `Property gold does not exist on type object`

So my question is how do I specify these properties?

Comment: It seems that error appears when the `lastFiveMatches.length === 0`.

Comment: He would get "Cannot read property of undefined" if length === 0. Problem is that he doesn't have typed lastFiveResults property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the interfaces `Item` and `ResultItem`:

```
export interface ResultItem {
  idresults: number;
  gold: number; 
  mana: number;
  xp: number;
}

export interface Stats {
  lastFiveResults: ResultItem[];
}
```

... and then:

```
data.lastFiveMatches[0].gold;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare like this:

```
export interface Stat {
    idresults: number, 
    gold:  number, 
    mana:  number, 
    xp:  number
}
```

and to initialize:

```
yourStats: Stat[]= [];

fooMethod() {    
    for (let i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        console.log('1');
        this.yourStats.push({idresults: i, gold: i, mana: i, xp: i})
    } 
    console.log(`Your stats is`, this.yourStats);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define another interface to specify the type of properties in your object.

```
interface myObject {
  idresults: number,
  gold: number,
  mana: number,
  xp: number
}

export interface Stats {

    lastFiveResults: myObject[];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class Stats {
    lastFiveResults: Object[]=[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
}
```

in your ts file:

```
data= new Stats();
console.log(data.lastFiveMatches[0].gold)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `interface` or `type` for your object within the list

```
export interface Stats {
    lastFiveResults: MyObject[];
}

export interface MyObject {
  idresults: number
  gold: number
  mana: number
  xp: number
}
```

Please see this [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZRkxgGc4BvAKDhrgBtMSYAxBAN2ACVgSBXO0gC44AWQCeAeQBGAK2DYYAbQC6AbkoBfSpVCRYiFGiy5Rk2fPhUaCACZQe-IXCS8AtlLTU4Acwh0bwi7unjSumEiYgW4eUF7gUcGxWpR0wPBMxCTChJlwALwUXgxMrBzcfAJZcIpeNOS29hVOAKwADK0AND5+AXDNAGwA7IMALJ1wYRHCAMytzdOD4-FwAIwAHO0aHbUUDQ6Vwm0rXb7+wiMAnABM02vHE+GRcP2tV4uDXcsrI21bO-V2fYtV4nHrCK4jFatFZXLqTJ6zaYXZojT5gYR3Vp-Wi7QFNKptaags5wSHNYZrOGPcH9GEotEYqHY2gAxqOAmtVHdEnTN5Xfr9KlTUlvDZEuDLLFeZSabQpNKIVCufJwDKkAB0xRY7C4QJIilaynVpxs6koQA).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (data.lastFiveMatches && data.lastFiveMatches.length > 0) {    
   const something = data.lastFiveMatches[0].gold || 0;
}
```